# MapBox - Theme change on existing Style

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-studio

Is there a way to change my existing style theme after I've created a theme in Mapbox Studio? For example:

1. Clicked Mapbox studio
2. Clicked Styles
3. Clicked "New Style" button to create a new style
4. Selected a theme(assume Basic theme) and created the style.
5. Now I decide that I want to change that style into another monochromatic style without having to create a new style again.

I am trying to avoid creating a new style with a new url for development purposes.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

**No.**

Once you create a new style using a given template, you cannot retroactively use a different template for that style.

To switch the style in your app from Basic to Monochrome, you'll need to create a new style using the Monochrome template, then change the style URL in your project. (Luckily, a style URL is only one line of code to change.)